# Passing Custom Objects from thymeleaf View to a Controller

Tags: java, html, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

Trying to pass Custom made objects using to `th:value` from View to Controller but only able to pass Java's primitive Data types through `th:value`. Is there any way I can send complex objects through `th:value`

I am new to spring and trying out some random things.
It is a simple web application.

#### What I'm trying to do:

I have a form for creating a team. The form includes a text field for a team name and a bunch of checkboxes to select the team members. For each selected checkbox the corresponding member should be added into the team list.

I tried using thymeleaf's `th:value` attribute to pass objects from View to Controller. But I can only pass String values using th:value

teamCreationForm.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create your Team</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create your dream team</h1>

    <form method="post" th:object="${team}">

        <span>Name of the team</span>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}">

        <div th:each="player : ${playersList}">
            <input type="checkbox" name="players" th:value="${player}" th:valueType="com.example.kkvamshee.Cricket.Player">
            <span th:text="${player.name}">Player Name</span>
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Submit your team</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CreateTeamController.java

```java
package com.example.kkvamshee.Cricket.web;

import com.example.kkvamshee.Cricket.Player;
import com.example.kkvamshee.Cricket.Team;
import com.example.kkvamshee.Cricket.data.JdbcPlayerRepository;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/create-your-team")
public class CreateTeamController {

    ....

    @GetMapping
    public String showSelectTeamPage(Model model) {
        List<Player> playersList = playerRepo.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("playersList", playersList);
        model.addAttribute("team", new Team());

        return "teamCreationForm";
    }

    .....

}
```

Team.java

```java
package com.example.kkvamshee.Cricket;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.List;

@Data
public class Team {
    @NotNull private String name;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 3, message = "You can only have 3 members on the team")
    private List<Player> players;
}
```

#### Error Log

```
Field error in object 'team' on field 'players': rejected value [Player(name=vamshee, age=20, exp=1),Player(name=messi, age=32, exp=18),Player(name=ronaldo, age=34, exp=18)]; codes [typeMismatch.team.players,typeMismatch.players,typeMismatch.java.util.List,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [team.players,players]; arguments []; default message [players]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'players'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.kkvamshee.Cricket.Player' for property 'players[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

At the end of thid error log, there is "no matching editors or conversion strategy found".

I tried changing the `th:valueType` to `Integer` and it successfully casted corresponding text into Integer values. But i get this casting error doing the same thing with Team object or any other custom made object for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thymeleaf can know which object you are working with especially if you have it mapped correctly and accepting it appropriately. Look at the test I did with your code.

Please watch how the action is introduced in the form.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your effort,
But in my case, somehow, the error still remains the same. Adding the th:action attribute did not change things significantly.

Answer (score 2):

Template engine has to convert the `<input ... th:value="${player}">` tag into HTML(something a browser can understand) and the converted tag looks like `<input ... value="string returned by player.toString()">`.

So, the view has no idea of the Object `Player`. The value is just a simple string to the view. Spring needs some converter to convert the string to an appropriate Player Object.

This can be done by implementing `Converter<String, Player>` Interface and then registering the Converter in our application.

#### Implementation of Converter Interface :

```java
package com.example.kkvamshee.cricket.config;

import com.example.kkvamshee.cricket.Player;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@Slf4j
public class StringToPlayerConverter implements Converter<String, Player> {

    @Override
    public Player convert(String source) {
        String pattern = "Player\\(name=([a-zA-z0-9]+), age=([1-9]+), exp=([1-9]+)\\)";

        Matcher matcherResult = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(source);

        log.info("regex result : " + matcherResult.find());

        String name = matcherResult.group(1);
        int age = Integer.parseInt(matcherResult.group(2));
        int exp = Integer.parseInt(matcherResult.group(3));

        return new Player(name, age, exp);
    }
}
```

#### Registering the above Converter Object :

```java
package com.example.kkvamshee.cricket.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new StringToPlayerConverter());
    }
}
```

There are various methods to acheive this type conversion.

For more details refer to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)